# foreach inside foreach only returns last result?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm relatively new to PHP and arrays are giving me fits! I'm attempting to learn how to modify arrays and create new arrays from the modifications, but my attempts are only returning the last array key in the foreach loop.

```
function stuff() {
  $items = array('shirt', 'shoes', 'pants');
  $colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green');
  $list = array();
  foreach($items as $item) {
    foreach($colors as $color) {
      $list[$item] = array($color => 'available');
    }
  }
  return $list;
}
```

What I want this to return is:

```
Array
(
  [shirt] => Array
  (
    [red] => available
    [blue] => available
    [green] => available
  )

  [shoes] => Array
  (
    [red] => available
    [blue] => available
    [green] => available
  )

  [pants] => Array
  (
    [red] => available
    [blue] => available
    [green] => available
  )
)
```

However, it appears to be only returning the last item in the second array...

```
Array
(
  [shirt] => Array
  (
    [green] => available
  )

  [shoes] => Array
  (
    [green] => available
  )

  [pants] => Array
  (
    [green] => available
  )
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `$list[$item] = array($color => 'available');` to `$list[$item][$color] = 'available';` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: So by simply putting the variable inside square brackets it automatically defines that as a nested array? Meaning I don't actually have to do $var = array()?

Comment: @user3123255: The correct team would be **multi-dimensional` array**. See demo: https://eval.in/81495

Comment: @user3123255 exactly. you don't need to pre-declare every intermediate step. For example, `$arr = array(); $arr['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 1` is completely legal.

Comment: Sweet! That's definitely a tip to keep under the hat for future reference then!

Too bad I have to wait 10mins to accept an answer... lol

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick responses, much appreciated!

Comment: @user3123255 You may insert `$list[$item] = array();` just before the second foreach loop, but it’ll do hardly anything more than increasing the number of lines in your code.

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
 $list[$item] = array($color => 'available');
```

with

```
 $list[$item][$color] = 'available';
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code. Basically you are defining a new array each time you loop through the colors, replacing the previous.

```
function stuff() 
{
  $items = array('shirt', 'shoes', 'pants');
  $colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green');
  $list = array();
  foreach($items as $item) 
  {
      foreach($colors as $color) 
      {
         $list[$item][$color] = 'available';
      }
  }
 return $list;
}

print_r(stuff());
```